# How to use Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) for dependibility between 2 devices?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android application which is `GCM` based. I have an concept in mind but don't know how to go about it. What I want to do is that, suppose, My application `server` has 2 devices(1 and 2) as its `clients`. If I send a message to device 1 through GCM and it responds with an answer, I want the application server to send a message to device B based on the response from device A. For **eg.** If the response from device 1 is X, it should send `abc` as the message to device 2 and If the response from device 1 is Y, it should send `efg` as the message to device 2. Any idea how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a GCM message in device 1, make a request to your API with your desired response and make your server store that response somewhere(database), if needed. Then use that stored response, when you need to send GCM message to device 2.

1. Device 1 waits for GCM message
2. Device 1 sends a request to your api with response string
3. Server stores your response string
4. Server sends GCM message to device 2 with that stored response string.